# Javascript help document.querySelector('.classname'))

Tags: javascript, html

I have made a site, with firebase backend all fine - but I am trying to render a dynamic div that adds a card everytime a new database entry has been added  ( using  `constname.innerHTML += html)` that gets an image from database, then when you click the image,  opens a pop up which gets its info from firebase too. Think of an events website, where you have an image, and click it and it opens a popup with more info.

Only thing is that as soon as I target the wrapper using `const constname = document.querySelector('.classname'))` its like it stops all js that opens the pop up.

The image and pop up are in the same wrapper, then the fixed position popup is hidden until you click the `<div>` then that changes the class to block. it works 100% with static data, until ill `document.querySelector('.classname'))`

Any ideas?.

**My script is getting data frim this script**

```
.where('_fl_meta_.schema', '==', "events")
.onSnapshot((snapshot) =>{
    //console.log(snapshot.docChanges());
    snapshot.docChanges().forEach(change => {
        console.log(change, change.doc.data(), change.doc.id);
          // console.log(change, change.doc.data(), change.doc.id);
        if(change.type === 'added'){
            // add to web page
            renderEvent(change.doc.data(), change.doc.id,)
        }
        if(change.type === 'removed'){

        }
    })
});
```

**Its being rendered like this**

```
const events = document.querySelector('.div-block-47')

const renderEvent = (data, id) => {


//render the datecard
  const html = `
  <div class="eventtemplatewrap">
  <div data-w-id="1e8c9168-6e5b-5bc7-cca9-a09025a650e9" class="div-block-53">
    <div class="eventholder">
      <div id="myBtn" class="div-block-52"><img src="images/5e4c7f3e9492fc8f24c9b556_medium_image-1581902571605.jpg" srcset="images/5e4c7f3e9492fc8f24c9b556_medium_image-1581902571605-p-500.jpeg 500w, images/5e4c7f3e9492fc8f24c9b556_medium_image-1581902571605.jpg 720w" sizes="(max-width: 767px) 92vw, 460px" alt=""></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

  `;
  events.innerHTML += html
}
```

**HTML CODE**

```
<div data-w-tab="Events" class="tab-pane-tab-2 w-tab-pane w--tab-active">
      <div class="tab2-wrap">
        <div class="div-block-48"><img src="images/vectorpaint.svg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="div-block-47">




        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Have you checked the browser console for errors?

Comment: @Pointy - no errors :(

Comment: Well without more code for context, nobody will be able to help. Calling `document.querySelector()` is harmless in and of itself.

Comment: ok, what do you need?

Comment: I have no idea because I don't know 1 single thing about your code other than that it apparently includes a call to `document.querySelector()`.  What happens before that point? What does the code attempt to do with the return value?

Comment: Do you have more than 1 `.classname` ?

Comment: Have updated the question, does that help - Sorry im still new and learning this :) Appreciate your help

Comment: Any JS i try to add wether inline or other won't function if the `querySelector` its selecting it

Comment: @awran5 - i do have more than one class, .classname was an example :)

Comment: but what about the HTML code with the class `div-block-47`. It also could be that judging by the code when you cache the ` document.querySelector('.div-block-47')` html is not rendered

Comment: @MonteCristo Html is very simple -  Will Upload it